# How to insert plugin URL (wordpress.org)

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to upload plugin to wordpress.org but found it kinda difficult.
See Screenshot

[image]

When I click "Send Post>>" ,it says "You must supply a Plugin URL that is a link to a .zip file of the working plugin" . I've already uploaded the zip file on https://uploadfiles.io/. And the url is absolutely correct. 
Any ideas?

Comment: First of all, the link you've supplied doesn't lead to the zip file. It leads to a page where you can download the file. Secondly, it's not even a .zip file but a .rar.

Comment: Where do I upload the file then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link needs to be a direct link to the zip file.  Most file upload services won't allow this.  Chances are it will need to be on a file server.

Comment: Where can I upload the file then? Is there any problem with .rar?

Comment: A .rar is not a .zip.  First make it a zip file.  An easy way to host it would be to make a Github repository for your plugin and add the zip file to releases.